# Value must be specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was working on a discord bot, but when I try to use any commands I get this error.
  Operating system: Windows 10
  Language: Java Version 8 Update 171
  Code:https://pastebin.com/jDLspKF6

Error:
    C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Collection.js:195
          if (typeof value === 'undefined') throw new Error('Value must be specified.');
                                            ^

```
Error: Value must be specified.
    at Map.find (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Collection.js:195:47)
    at Client.bot.elevation.message [as elevation] (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\app.js:53:40)
    at Client.module.exports.message (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\events\message.js:8:24)
    at Client.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You should post your code instead of just posting error messages. [Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: Here is the code https://pastebin.com/jDLspKF6 , i tried to replace bot with client but still didnt worked

Comment: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50783040/edit) your question and post the relevant part of your source code there. Avoid posting unnecessary comments to your own question, since you can always edit it. See: [MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/). Good luck!

Comment: What line in your code snippet on pastebin is causing the error?  That isn't exactly an MCVE, so you should at least let us know where the bug is happening.

Comment: Language is Javascript, not Java :)

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from app.js at line 53 (from your error: `at Client.bot.elevation.message [as elevation] (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\c\app.js:53:40)`)

In your code at line 53 you're using [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find), and you're probably passing an undefined argument: check `settings.json` to make sure that `modrolename` exists ;)